# Umbraco : Refresh dropdown datatype items automatically on parent node publish

Tags: umbraco, dropdownbox

I have a dropdown datatype which has all the child nodes of a parent node. I can create this list manually. But the problem is, the child nodes will be created/deleted on the fly, which means I need to edit/remove the dropdown values manually each time.

Is there a way to add/remove items from dropdown list whenever my parent node is published??

Please let me know.

Comment: Which version of Umbraco do you use? The API works differently dependant on the version

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the latest version of Umbraco, you can register an event on document publish which will fire for every single event publish. In the event handler code you can then selectively fire for only the node you are concerned with.

http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Events/application-startup

Something like the following should do it

```
using Umbraco.Core;
using umbraco.BusinessLogic;
using umbraco.cms.businesslogic;
using umbraco.cms.businesslogic.web;

namespace Umbraco.Extensions.EventHandlers
{
    public class RegisterEvents : ApplicationEventHandler
    {
        protected override void ApplicationStarted(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
        {
            Document.BeforePublish += Document_BeforePublish;
        }

        private void Document_BeforePublish(Document sender, PublishEventArgs e)
        {
            //Do what you need to do. In this case logging to the Umbraco log
            Log.Add(LogTypes.Debug, sender.Id, "the document " + sender.Text + " is about to be published");


            if (sender.Id == YourIDAsAConstantOrConfigurableValue)
            {
               //Do your list building here
            }

            //cancel the publishing if you want.
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}
```

You can trigger selectively for your specific parent node based on either ID or based on document type alias

Hope that helps

Comment: If this answer is helpful I'd appreciate you marking this as an answer. If not - no worries